# Axios api call, export variable from inside a function

Tags: svelte

I have this function in request.js

```
import Axios from "axios"
export async function get(res, req, next) {
    var resp = await Axios.get("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products");
    let pairs = resp.data.map(a => a.id);
    console.log(pairs)
}
```

in my component I have this :

```
<script>

        import { get } from "../data/request.js";
    
        function getSomething() {
            get();
        }

</script>

<h1>get something here</h1>
<button on:click={getSomething}>Get !</button>
```

This way I manage to get the pairs in the console but I use the whole function, how can I use the variable "pairs" on its own in my component ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
import Axios from "axios"
export async function get(res, req, next) {
    var resp = await Axios.get("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products");
    let pairs = resp.data.map(a => a.id);
    console.log(pairs)
return pairs;
}
```

Add the return keyword

```
<script>

        import { get } from "../data/request.js";
    let pairs
        function getSomething() {
        pairs=   get();
      console.log(pairs)
        }

</script>

<h1>get something here</h1>
<button on:click={getSomething}>Get !</button>
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for your time and your answer. But is there a way to get pairs without calling the function ? I want to do an {#each} loop on the data but it can only iterate over an array, and if i do {#each pairs as pair} for example i will get an error

Comment: I tried return [pairs] at the end of the function but it does not work